# How to create divs based on number present in input field on button click, ONLY ONCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

what i am trying to do is as follows:

1. Get data from json file on button click.
2. Show the data in separate boxes,different for each element of array. For example, if my json gives me 3 rows of data, there should be 3 boxes.
3. Place the boxes in a grid of 2X2.
4. Exactly like in this image[Wireframe for foodcourts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fkMf.png)

Step 1 i achieved easily. I can also generate boxes on button click but not as shown in image. Also, each time the button is clicked, it adds to the div.I would really appreciate some help. Here is my code:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document
    </title>
  </head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    .shape{
      text-align:center;
      background-image:url(dark-triangles.png);
      width:200px;
      height:60px;
      line-height:60px;
      color:white;
      margin:10px;
      position:relative;
      transition-property: background;
      transition-duration: -10s;
      transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
    .shape:before{
      content:"";
      width:0px;
      height:0px;
      border-top:60px solid rgba(107,255,55,105);
      border-left:60px solid transparent;
      position:absolute;
      right:0%;
      top:0px;
    }
    .shape:hover{
      background: #ff7b29;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    .sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 250px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-image: url("doodles.png");
      background-color: #cccccc;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    /*.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    }*/
    /*.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
    }*/
    /*.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    }*/
    /*@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }*/
    .div1
    {
      width:400px;
      height:auto;
      background:none;
      margin:auto;
      border:2px solid black;
      margin-top:70px;
    }
    .divcontent
    {
      width:auto;
      height:auto;
      background:none;
      margin:auto;
      border:2px solid black;
      margin-top:70px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <body ng-controller="myController" background="cloudy-day.png" style="color:black;">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <!--  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>!-->
      <input value={{len}}>
      </input>
    <button class="shape" id="orders" >
      Orders
      <button class="shape" id="users">
        Users
        <button class="shape" ng-click="fcclicked()">
          Food Courts
          <button class="shape">
            Delivery Locations
            </div>
          <div class="div1"; id="d1">
            <p align="center">Click one of the buttons to load content.....
            </p>
            <div ng-repeat="x in names">
              {{ x.id}} 
              {{ x.name }}
              {{ x.address }}
            </div>  
            <!--             <script language="javascript">
function cdiv()
{
/*  var nums=document.getElementById();
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.innerHTML = "Hello";
div.style.display="inline-block";
div.style.margin="10px";
document.getElementById("d1").appendChild(div);*/
}
</script>!-->
          </div>
          <script>
            angular.module('myApp', [])
              .controller('myController', function($scope,$http) {
              $scope.fcclicked= function(){
                alert("hiii");
                $http.get('http:/18.220.71.157:8080/foodcourt/foodcourt/list')
                  .success(function(response) {
                  $scope.names = response.foodCourts;
                  $scope.len=response.foodCourts.length;
                  //var newEle = angular.element("<table class='square'></div>");
                  //var target = document.getElementById('d1');
                  //angular.element(target).append(newEle);
                  /*for( i =1 ; i <$scope.len ;i++){
                        var newEle = angular.element("<div class='square' id='myddiv'></div>");
                         angular.element(target).append(newEle);
                         }*/
                }
                          );
              }
            }
                         );
          </script>
          <style>
            .square {
              width: 100px;
              height: 100px;
              background: red;
              display:inline-block;
              margin:10px;
            }
          </style>
          <!--<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).click(function(e){  
if(e.target.id=="orders")
{   
//$("#d1").append('');
}
if(e.target.id=="users")
{   
}
// $("#d1").fadeIn();
//$("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
//$("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
});
});
</script>
<!--<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}
function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>!-->
          <style>
            .minidiv
            {
            }
          </style>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: okay so if I understand right what you want, you want the data to be rendered inside DIVS for each entry right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly like in the image

Comment: [Input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) tags do not need closing tags, however, [button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) tags do require closing tags.

Comment: can you put the code inside a JSfiddle?

Comment: ok i will give it a try.. i have never used jsfiddle.. please give me a minute...

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there were a lot of problems

- The style tag should b always in the head
- The button must be closed `<button></button>`
- The input tag should be closed like this `<input />`
- the script tag resides preferably in the head or in the bottom of the
  body

I fixed some styling to float the divs and so you can have the same idea that you wanted, you modify the code as you want now:

```js
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.fcclicked = function() {
          alert("hiii");
          $http.get('http:/18.220.71.157:8080/foodcourt/foodcourt/list')
            .success(function(response) {
              $scope.names = response.foodCourts;
              $scope.len = response.foodCourts.length;
            });
        };
      })
```

```css
.shape {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(dark-triangles.png);
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: -10s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
  }
  
  .shape:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 60px solid rgba(107, 255, 55, 105);
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0px;
  }
  
  .shape:hover {
    background: #ff7b29;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("doodles.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .div1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    background: none;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .divcontent {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: none;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: 70px;
  }
  
  .square {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 48%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document
  </title>
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body ng-controller="myController" background="cloudy-day.png" style="color:black;">
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <input value={{len}} />
    <button class="shape" id="orders">Orders</button>
    <button class="shape" id="users">Users</button>
    <button class="shape" ng-click="fcclicked()">Food Courts</button>
    <button class="shape">Delivery Locations</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div1" id="d1">
    <p align="center">Click one of the buttons to load content.....
    </p>
    <div class="square" ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x.id}} {{ x.name }} {{ x.address }}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was quite helpful. Also, thank you for letting me on the nitty gritty details. I will definitely incorporate those in other pages. Just a request, sir, can you please elaborate what chnages did you perform in css, and how they affect the output? Thanks

Comment: you're welcome! I've added floating to the div with a width of 48% and left 1% margin left and 1% margin right, also I added padding and the box-sizing:border-box so it the padding won't affect the width of the div :)

Comment: i tried upvoting but my rep isn't enough! Don't worry as soon as i reah 15 i will definitely do that! your answer deserves that! :)